# Loop through multidimensional Hash of Arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hash, foreach

I have a multidimensional hash of arrays that represent a student's grade in each subject for the first four assignments.

```
my %students_grades = (
    Colton => {
        English     => [ 90, 95, 80, 75 ],
        Mathematics => [ 77, 89,94, 100 ],
    },
);
```

The syntax is a bit off but here's the code that creates the hash of arrays above.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %students_grades;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'}[0] = 90;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'}[1] = 95;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'}[2] = 80;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'}[3] = 75;

$students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}[0] = 77;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}[1] = 89;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}[2] = 94;
$students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}[3] = 100;
```

How do I loop through the student's grades he received in History using a foreach loop? Right now I'm looping through it using a for loop.

```
my $num_of_grades = scalar @{$students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}};
for (my $i=0; $i <= $num_of_grades; $i++) {
    print $students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}[$i] . "\n";
}
```

This is a representation of my code but in my actual program my hash of arrays is more complicated so I want to loop through the hash of arrays using a foreach loop because it'll be easier to handle. How do I do that?

Comment: Your hash is not multidimensional in the way you think. The `=>` is a comma in Perl. What you have is this: `( 'key: Colton' => 'value: English', 'key: Array(0x123456)' => 'value: Colton', 'key: Mathematics' => [ ... ] )` with the overall structure being a hash (not a hashref).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (my $i=0; $i<@array; ++$i) {
   my $ele = $array[$i];
   ...
}
```

can be written simply as

```
for my $ele (@array) {
   ...
}
```

so you could have used the following:

```
for my $grade (@{ $students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'} }) {
   print("$grade\n");
}
```

---

```
my $grade = $students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'}[0];
```

is short for

```
my $grade = $students_grades{'Colton'}->{'English'}->[0];
```

which means you can do

```
my $grades = $students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'};
my $grade = $grades->[0];
```

which means you could also have used the following:

```
my $grades = $students_grades{'Colton'}{'English'};
for my $grade (@$grades) {
   print("$grade\n");
}
```

Knowing this allows one to easily escalate to the following:

```
for my $student_name (keys(%students_grades)) {
   my $student_grades_by_class = $students_grades{$student_name};
   for my $class_name (keys(%$student_grades_by_class)) {
      my $grades = $student_grades_by_class->{$class_name};
      for my $grade (@$grades) {
         print("$student_name: $class_name: $grade\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In perl, `for` and `foreach` mean the same.

But the thing here is - you don't have a hash of arrays - you have a hash of array *references*.

So:

```
 $students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}
```

is actually an array reference.

So you can dereference it:

```
foreach my $grade ( @{ $students_grades{'Colton'}{'History'}  } ) {
    print "$grade\n";
}
```